# How to run classic ASP scripts under IIS 5.1 (WinXP Pro) alongside .NET & CF?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, isapi-extension

I'm running into a problem setting up my development environment. I've been working on ColdFusion and .NET applications up until recently I haven't needed to touch IIS. Now, I have to set up a classic ASP application for some one-off work.

I added a virtual directory in IIS and pointed it at the actual codebase on my local machine. I then set the security to low (for ISAPI extensions, i.e. ASP) and allowed for script execution. For some reason though, if I hit any .asp page it says the page cannot be found. However, HTML and static files load up just fine.

EDIT: URLScan fix seems to have done it. Fired up the app in another browser (i.e. not IE6), and I'm getting better error reporting. Looks like we're missing some includes, but it is executing the scripts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your URL scan settings and see if .asp is an allowed file extension

On my XP machine the relevant file is located at C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\urlscan\urlscan.ini

Comment: Good call, seems to have gotten it running. Now I have new issues to resolve, but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the "Active Server Pages" web service extension is set to an allowed status.

Check out: http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-does-iis-hang-and/or-stop-serving-asp-pages.html

Also, you should be aware that a virtual directory may affect the include file paths in the asp pages themselves.  If the original asp application does not use a virtual directory, then your local copy shouldn't either.

Comment: Yeah by default now it's turned off

Comment: I'm having trouble finding that GUI under XP Pro's IIS 5.1. I like to think I'm pretty sharp, but I'm lost. :)